# Pop up dialog from one button on the main window, PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

i have created a main window with a table, and two buttons, and i also have created a dialog window, with a label, a line edit for user input, and two buttons..

I would like the dialog to pop up once one button in the main window is pressed, take the input the user gives, and after he presses "accept" in the dialog, i want the dialog to close and get back to the main window how would i do that?

Main menu:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(670, 492)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.firstbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.firstbutton.setObjectName("firstbutton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.firstbutton)
        self.secondbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.secondbutton.setObjectName("secondbutton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.secondbutton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 670, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Second column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Third"))
        self.firstbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add"))
        self.secondbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Dialog:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    # Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'dialog.ui'
    #
    # Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.4.1
    #
    # WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(358, 126)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.dialoglabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.dialoglabel.setObjectName("dialoglabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.dialoglabel)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.dialoglineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.dialoglineedit.setObjectName("dialoglineedit")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.dialoglineedit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.dialoglabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "dialoglabel"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Acept"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cancel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ahh, I just looked at this for a PyQt5 course I am developing. First you will need to import the form.

```
from dialog import Ui_Dialog as Form
```

and Then create a function that will open the dialog:

```
def open_dialog(self):
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dialog.ui = Form()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.exec_()
    dialog.show()
```

which I will connect to your first button:

```
self.firstbutton.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)
```

In the dialog.py, you can get rid of these lines:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

They are only needed if you are invoking the dialog directly. To be a bit clearer, `__name__ != "__main__"`

Ok, so in dialog.py, I will create 2 new functions and assign them to buttons.

```
# 2 sample functions
def return_accept(self):
    print("yes")

def return_cancel(self):
    print("no")
```

and bind these events to the buttons:

```
# connect the two functions
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.return_yes)
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.return_no)
```

**Completed Code**

app.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from dialog import Ui_Dialog as Form

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(670, 492)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.firstbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.firstbutton.setObjectName("firstbutton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.firstbutton)
        self.secondbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.secondbutton.setObjectName("secondbutton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.secondbutton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 670, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.firstbutton.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Second column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Third"))
        self.firstbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add"))
        self.secondbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete"))

    def open_dialog(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        dialog.ui = Form()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.exec_()
        dialog.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**dialog.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(358, 126)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.dialoglabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.dialoglabel.setObjectName("dialoglabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.dialoglabel)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.dialoglineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.dialoglineedit.setObjectName("dialoglineedit")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.dialoglineedit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        # connect the two functions
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.return_yes)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.return_no)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.dialoglabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "dialoglabel"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Acept"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cancel"))

    # 2 sample functions
    def return_accept(self):
        print("yes")

    def return_cancel(self):
        print("no")
```

Comment: You should not run both dialog.exec_() and  dialog.show(). It should be one or the other, or else you will need to click OK twice.

Comment: @VectorVictor if you have tested you can update the answer.

Comment: Okay, edit submitted. Thanks for the post though, it was helpful

Comment: This answer got my upvote. You put a lot of work into this and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but I think you mixed the function up.
You call: self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.return_yes)

but defined is:

2 sample functions
def return_accept(self):
print("yes")